# mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_object for python?

Tags: php, python, mysql

I'm using MySQLdb in python to connect to a mysql database (duh) and am really missing the functionality that's built into PHP, namely:

`mysql_fetch_array` and `mysql_fetch_object`

What is the equivalent in Python so that I can start getting my scripts ported?

Comment: First result of googling (is this officially a verb now!?) "python mysql" - http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/ - is a DBAPI 2.0 compliant interface, so `.fetch()` and `.fetchall()` on cursor objects...

Comment: I ask this because perhaps there's a "specific way" that everyone's doing it and that's why I'm the only one pulling out hair?

Comment: As always: `mysql_*()` is outdated and should be used anymore. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` instead.

Comment: Not really - Create a connection object, create a cursor, execute a query on the cursor, then iterate over the cursor object and you get the equiv of mysql_fetch_array

Comment: So using PDO would probably be that "preferred method" or once not quite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was the `DictCursor`:

```
cur = con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```